# Graph Coloring Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

Given T(n) as a star graph with n edges. *(Basically T(n) is a graph that has one vertex u in the center, and from u there is one edge to each vertex v1,...,vn.)*

It is easily know that star-graphs are at least 2-colorable. Assume you have two separate star-graphs, Tk and Tm, for some positive integers k and m. Pick one random vertex from each graph and connect them with an edge. What information would you infer is true from the resulting graph of T?

**Answer Choices**

1) The graphs chromatic number is 3

2) MAX_DEG(T) = max(k,m) + 1

3) T is two-colorable

4) MAX-DEG(T) = max(k,m)

Comment: Which of the four answers have you managed to eliminate by finding counterexamples?

Comment: Surely you are able to make some progress on this problem on your own. Tell us what you know about the problem, please!

Comment: All I really know is that Max-Deg is the highest number of degrees in the graph. Colorable means can a graph be colored using only x amount of colors. I also know that the chromatic number is the minimum coloring number of a graph. Despite this information I have no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: choose some specific star graphs and link them following the given rules. check the validity of the answer options. try to generalize your insights.

Comment: I drew it out and on the 2nd star graph I inverted the colors. So I was able to draw the graph's connected together as being 2 colorable, but I'm not sure if that's right. Each question is 33% of my grade, and I don't want to gamble that unless I'm positive.

Comment: I believe I have the answer down to either answer choice 2 or 3. Each seperate graph k and m individually is max-deg = 1 however when you connected a node the max deg of the whole thing is 2. So answer choice 2 also looks correct because the max of k and m are both 1. However if you add 1 to that you get 2. However I'm still stuck because the graph is also 2-colorable is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**3** Is **true**: Color the first graph $T_k$ with two colors, lets call them for simplicity red and blue. The vertex you picked from this graph has one color. Color the vertex picked from the second graph with the other color.

As the second graph $T_m$  is 2-colorable, once we colored one single vertex with a color we can complete it to a 2-coloring of this $T_m$. It is easy to check that this is a good $2$-coloring of the big graph.

To complete the proof, it is easy to argue that the graph is not one -colorable.

**1** is (always) **false**, because we just proved the graph is 2-colorable.

**2** is (sometimes) **false**, you can see this by connecting vertices of degree 1.

**4** is (sometimes) **false** you can see this by connecting the centers of the graphs.

Comment: If you can explain to me why #2 is false I'll mark this answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: Because the max of (k,m) would be the max-deg of (k) which is 1 and the max-deg of (m) would be 1. However that means that the max(k,m) would be 1. However if you add +1 to that you get 2 which is the maximum degree when the graphs are connected.

Comment: @user127662 Draw two star graphs, and connect two leafs. What is the maximum degree ?

Comment: The maximum degree is 2. So since max(k,m) is 1, if you add +1 to that you get 2. That means 2=2. So how would "MAX_DEG(T) = max(k,m) + 1" not be correct then?

Comment: @user127662 No, why is $k=1$ and $m=1$? Note that $k,m$ represent the number of "arms" of the star... If $k=5$ your star has 5 arms, what is the degree of the central vertex?

Comment: Yup, you're right. That was my issue. I though K and M represented two individual star graphs. I didn't realize that k and m were actually the number of edges of each star. Thank you very much!